# Enabling SSLCompression in apache

Tags: tls, openssl, apache

I am trying to enable `SSLCompression` in apache (localhost) for testing purpose.

My apache version is 2.4.18 and I have added the `SSLCompression on` line in both `apache2.conf` file and my `.htaccess` file. But still I cannot enable it.

I have downloaded the following version of openssl
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.0/openssl-1.1.0-pre6.tar.gz

I am using openssl to generate the certificates and test it. When I run the command

```
apps/openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

I get the following response

```
SSL handshake has read 2625 bytes and written 310 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
```

where it says I do not have the compression enabled. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

FYI I have enabled `mod_rewrite` and `mod_deflate` modules in apache2.

Comment: If your openssl is not horribly outdated, it probably doesn't support ssl compression because that is terribly insecure!

Comment: I am actually doing some research work so I really need to enable it. Are you recommending me to use a very old openssl version to get it enabled?

Comment: @Josef well we have installed the openssl1.1.0 and used the `apps/openssl s_client -comp` command to verify, where the SSLCompression was actually ON. it is off only when I try to access through apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [OpenSSL 1.1.0 release notes](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x2):

> CRIME protection: disable compression by default, even if OpenSSL is
>        compiled with zlib enabled. Applications can still enable compression
>        by calling SSL_CTX_clear_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION), or by
>        using the SSL_CONF library to configure compression.

As a consequence, OpenSSL must be compiled with the good option and Apache needs to enable compression the right way...

I suggest you to use an older branch previously compiled with zlib option. For instance using Ubuntu 16.04:

```
cd /tmp
sudo apt-get build-dep openssl
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev zlibc
apt-get source openssl
cd openssl-1.0.2g/
sed -i -e "s/no-zlib/zlib/g" debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb libssl-dev_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb openssl_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

This, keeping `SSLCompression on` in Apache, should do the trick I think.

**EDIT**: After testing, it appears to be working:

```
root@test# echo "" | openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 | grep zlib
...
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
    Compression: 1 (zlib compression)
DONE
```

Comment: Hi @Jyo. +1 for the answer. It works exactly in the way I want. Is it possible for you to explain me how this works? I mean, I thought `SSLCompression` has been removed by apache sources. but from what you have shared it looks it is `openssl` who decides wether to have the compression or not (ignoring `SSLCompression on` config in apache)

Comment: Hi @MohammedFawzan, Apache relies here on OpenSSL for everything linked to the TLS layer, so to enable TLS compression, OpenSSL has to support it. By default for years now, shipped version of OpenSSL disable support of compression for security reason, that's why you had to manually enable it before being able to use it.
However, Apache config is not ignored, because switching `SSLCompression` to `off` in Apache configuration will effectively disable Compression.

Comment: Crystal clear. +1 for your effort.

Comment: I would highly appreciate your help on this. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157386/enabled-ssl-compression-is-not-visible-to-the-public

Comment: Would the process be similar for openssl1.1.1 in more recent ubuntu's?

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't seem to work with > TLS1